# Spark on Mesos using docker images

Tags: docker, apache-spark, networking, mesos

I have an issue running spark on Mesos using docker.

**Cluster Details:**

> 3 nodes mesos cluster (M1 - Mesos master, M2 and M3 - Mesos slaves)
>
> OS: CentOS

I am able to run a spark application on Mesos without Docker but when i try using the docker (Spark deployment mode - Cluster), i notice the following

- The executors are launched on 2 mesos slaves (M2 and M3)
- The driver is on M2
- The executor on M3 is not able to communicate with the driver container on M2 (the executor is trying to contact the driver at 127.0.0.1)
- The executor on M2 is able to contact the driver on the same machine and the application completes as well.

**Questions**

> 1. Do i need to setup the networking to make Docker work?
> 2. What is the default docker networking setup in Mesos?